# submit button overlap other div

Tags: html, css

in my page I have a table. on top of the table I have a menu with dropdown lists. When opening a list it will cover the titles of the table. Some of these titles are submit button and because of this they will overlap the menu dropdown list. Then basically I can't click the element of the lists as the submit button is ahead of the dropdown (but it should be on the background). I'll post a screen of what happens. the grey sqare is the menu list and the green is the title of the table. The problem only occurs when the title of the table is a submit button. If it's just text, I won't have issue.

this is the css class of the submit button

```
.order{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    vertical-align:middle;
    position: relative;
    bottom:-10px;
    width:150px;
}
```

what I want to do is to be able to click the dropdown elements without having the submit button interfere with them.
Sorry for my english,

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to set

```
z-index: 9999;
```

of the list

Tell me if works

Comment: sorry, you mean in the css of the list?

Comment: No problem. Marks the answer as correct, so people can check it ;) bye